# GeoPandas reprojection of Point in Lat/Lon to UTM give Inf, Inf

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

When using geopandas, have tried to convert some Points in Lat/Lon to UTM. However, the conversion gives me Point(inf inf)... what is wrong with my code? Can someoone point out the problem to me. Thks

```
GPS =  pd.read_excel('coordinates.xls', sheet_name='GPS', usecols = "A,B,F,G", header = 0)
GPS.columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Lat', 'Lon']

GPS_LatLon = GPS[["Lat","Lon"]]
geodf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(GPS_LatLon,
                   crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'},
                   geometry=GPS_LatLon.apply(lambda row: shapely.geometry.Point((row.Lat, row.Lon)), axis=1))

geodf = geodf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:32633'})

geodf["x"] = geodf.geometry.apply(lambda row:row.x)
geodf["y"] = geodf.geometry.apply(lambda row:row.y)

GPS_UTM = pd.DataFrame(geodf)
GPS_UTM.to_excel("GPS_utm.xls")
```

This is my data after the GeoDataFrame Step

```
        Lat         Lon               geometry
0     1.416176  13.869467  POINT (1.416 13.869)
1     1.416176  13.869466  POINT (1.416 13.869)
2     1.416176  13.869465  POINT (1.416 13.869)
3     1.416177  13.869465  POINT (1.416 13.869)
4     1.416178  13.869463  POINT (1.416 13.869)
5     1.416179  13.869462  POINT (1.416 13.869)
6     1.416180  13.869460  POINT (1.416 13.869)
7     1.416181  13.869458  POINT (1.416 13.869)
```

But the output give me

```
       Lat         Lon         geometry    x    y
0     1.416176  13.869467  POINT (inf inf)  inf  inf
1     1.416176  13.869466  POINT (inf inf)  inf  inf
2     1.416176  13.869465  POINT (inf inf)  inf  inf
3     1.416177  13.869465  POINT (inf inf)  inf  inf
4     1.416178  13.869463  POINT (inf inf)  inf  inf
5     1.416179  13.869462  POINT (inf inf)  inf  inf
6     1.416180  13.869460  POINT (inf inf)  inf  inf
7     1.416181  13.869458  POINT (inf inf)  inf  inf
```

Answer (score 6):

I could be wrong about this, but I think you should be passing (lon, lat) to shapely.geometry.Point, not (lat, lon).

Comment: It would be helpful to please show what this suggested change looks like in the code

Comment: Use `geopandas.points_from_xy(x=longitude, y=latitude)`. See the documentation (https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.points_from_xy.html): "In case of geographic coordinates, it is assumed that longitude is captured by x coordinates and latitude by y."